# __init__() missing 1 required positional argument: 'units'

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

```
import pandas as pd
import tensorflow as tf
import keras
import numpy as np

dataset = pd.read_csv('GalaxyZoo1_DR_table2.csv')

X = dataset.iloc[:, 3:13].values
y = dataset.iloc[:, 13:16].values

from sklearn.impute import SimpleImputer
imputer = SimpleImputer(missing_values=np.nan, strategy='mean')
imputer = imputer.fit(X[:, :])
X[:,:] = imputer.transform(X[:, :])

from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size = 0.2, random_state = 0)

from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
sc = StandardScaler()
X_train = sc.fit_transform(X_train)
X_test = sc.transform(X_test)

# Importing the Keras libraries and packages
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense

# Initialising the ANN
classifier = Sequential()

# Adding the input layer and the first hidden layer
classifier.add(Dense(output_dim = 6, init = 'uniform', activation = 'relu', input_dim = 10))

# Adding the second hidden layer
classifier.add(Dense(output_dim = 6, init = 'uniform', activation = 'relu'))

# Adding the output layer
classifier.add(Dense(output_dim = 3, init = 'uniform', activation = 'sigmoid'))

# Compiling the ANN
classifier.compile(optimizer = 'adam', loss = 'binary_crossentropy', metrics = ['accuracy'])

# Fitting the ANN to the Training set
classifier.fit(X_train, y_train, batch_size = 10, nb_epoch = 10)

# Part 3 - Making the predictions and evaluating the model

# Predicting the Test set results
y_pred = classifier.predict(X_test)
y_pred = (y_pred > 0.5)
```

I sourced this code from:https://deep-r.medium.com/hello-there-this-is-my-first-blog-2b98a4690f82
I am getting the following error message:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-30-0f8b63331cfa> in <module>
     30 
     31 # Adding the input layer and the first hidden layer
---> 32 classifier.add(Dense(output_dim = 6, init = 'uniform', activation = 'relu', input_dim = 10))
     33 
     34 # Adding the second hidden layer

TypeError: __init__() missing 1 required positional argument: 'units'
```

I am a newbie to keras/tensorflow.... as my name implies. Please help!

Comment: There is no need to pass all arguments as keywords, specially since the names have changed, just use Dense(6, activation="relu", kernel_initializer="uniform)

Answer (score 0):

The error message is saying that it need an additional parameter called `units` in order to initialize a Dense object. According to [documentation](https://keras.io/api/layers/core_layers/dense/), you use an integer as the first parameter when creating a Dense class object, it will use as a `unit` parameter:

```
classifier.add(Dense(6, output_dim = 6, init = 'uniform', activation = 'relu', input_dim = 10))
```

Comment: how to decide on the number? thanks